# AppSource validation failing for Azure AD web app because of missing version number

Tags: azure-active-directory, office-store, appsource

My Azure AD web app fails validation in AppSource with the following errors:

> 7.9 Your add-in’s packages must be correctly formatted and conform to the current manifest schema. For Office Add-ins, this is manifest
>   schema version 1.1.
>
> For detailed manifest schema information, see Schema reference for
>   Office Add-ins manifests (v1.1) and Schema reference for manifests of
>   SharePoint Add-ins. Also see What are some common errors to avoid when
>   submitting my add-in to AppSource? in AppSource submission FAQ.
>
> 10.3 The version number you specify for your add-in on the Seller Dashboard submission form must exactly match the version number in the
>   add-in manifest.

How should I resolve this? The app is indeed registered as an Azure AD web app. The errors are however referring to the schema for Office- and SharePoint Add-ins which does not apply to my case. The [schema for Azure AD applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-application-manifest) does not specify a field for version number.

Answer (score 0):

When you submit an Azure Web app to AppSource using the Seller Dashboard, you are prompted to complete the 'Version' field in the first page of the listing. 
The version number for Web Apps using Azure AD should follow the below structure:

n.n

n.n.n

[image]